# Tela para configurar conexão com Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Atualmente estou usando o seguinte código para executar conexões com meu DB

```
public class ConexaoDAO {
    public Connection getConexao() {
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ip:porta/tabela", "usuario", "senha");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Porém gostaria de conseguir configurar o "ip" e "porta" sem necessitar alterar o código para isso, pois pretendo que esse programa possa se comunicar com um DB em um servidor não local (localhost).

Havia pensado em criar um arquivo onde eu pudesse colocar os dados e assim que eu executasse o programa, ele leria as informações a partir desse arquivo para executar a conexão.

Alguma ideia/dica de como resolver essa situação?

Obs.: todas as classes que comunicam com o DB usam essa classe para efetuar a conexão.

Grato pela atenção.

Comment: Você quer salvar esses dados a parte, é isso? Fazer telinha só pra isso acho um desperdicio de tempo.

Comment: basicamente sim, como um arquivo de configuração. 
Alguma outra sugestão? havia pensado em definir um ip fixo para o servidor dentro da rede, mas não me sinto confortável com essa ideia.

Comment: Ia sugerir um arquivo `.properties` ao inves de tela, mas já responderam a respeito abaixo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal usar um padrão factory com getters e setters?

```
public class MySqlConnectionFactory {
    private String host;
    private int porta;
    private String database;
    private String usuario;
    private String senha;

    public MySqlConnectionFactory() {
    }

    public MySqlConnectionFactory(String host, int porta, String database, String usuario, String senha) {
        this.host = host;
        this.porta = porta;
        this.database = database;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.senha = senha;
    }
    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public int getPorta() {
        return porta;
    }

    public void setPorta(int porta) {
        this.porta = porta;
    }

    public String getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }

    public void setDatabase(String database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public Connection criarConexao() {
        if (host == null) throw new IllegalStateException("O host não foi definido.");
        if (porta == 0) throw new IllegalStateException("A porta não foi definida.");
        if (database == null) throw new IllegalStateException("O database não foi definido.");
        if (usuario == null) throw new IllegalStateException("O usuário não foi definido.");
        if (senha == null) throw new IllegalStateException("A senha não foi definida.");

        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + porta + "/" + database, usuario, senha);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Ou se preferir, use o padrão builder:

```
public class MySqlConnectionBuilder {
    private final String host;
    private final int porta;
    private final String database;
    private final String usuario;
    private final String senha;

    public MySqlConnectionBuilder() {
        this(null, 0, null, null, null);
    }

    public MySqlConnectionBuilder(String host, int porta, String database, String usuario, String senha) {
        this.host = host;
        this.porta = porta;
        this.database = database;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public MySqlConnectionBuilder withHost(String newHost) {
        return new MySqlConnectionBuilder(newHost, porta, database, usuario, senha);
    }

    public int getPorta() {
        return porta;
    }

    public MySqlConnectionBuilder withPorta(int novaPorta) {
        return new MySqlConnectionBuilder(host, novaPorta, database, usuario, senha);
    }

    public String getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }

    public MySqlConnectionBuilder withDatabase(String newDatabase) {
        return new MySqlConnectionBuilder(host, porta, newDatabase, usuario, senha);
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public MySqlConnectionBuilder withUsuario(String novoUsuario) {
        return new MySqlConnectionBuilder(host, porta, database, novoUsuario, senha);
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public MySqlConnectionBuilder withSenha(String novaSenha) {
        return new MySqlConnectionBuilder(host, porta, database, usuario, novaSenha);
    }

    public Connection criarConexao() {
        if (host == null) throw new IllegalStateException("O host não foi definido.");
        if (porta == 0) throw new IllegalStateException("A porta não foi definida.");
        if (database == null) throw new IllegalStateException("O database não foi definido.");
        if (usuario == null) throw new IllegalStateException("O usuário não foi definido.");
        if (senha == null) throw new IllegalStateException("A senha não foi definida.");

        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + porta + "/" + database, usuario, senha);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Um construtor recebendo todas essas propriedades cairia bem hein =)

Comment: @diegofm Pensei nisso também, mas daí nesse caso, já seria mais fácil construir a string de conexão inteira de uma vez.

Comment: @diegofm Alterei a resposta colocando um builder também.

Comment: Esse builder ficou mais avançada mas bem mais interessante com essas opções de alterar apenas determinados parâmetros ao inves de todos da conexao.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode deixar toda a sua configuração num arquivo `application.properties`, comumente colocado na sua pasta resources (pensando na estrutura de projeto maven) e ler as configurações dele. Isso inclusive te permite ter vários arquivos, de acordo com seu ambiente. Por exemplo: `dev.application.properties` e `prod.application.properties`. Também tem a vantagem de permitir o versionamento dessa configuração.

A outra opção é colocar essas informações nas variáveis de ambiente. Não gosto dessa abordagem especialmente se você tiver que colocar as senhas lá, e você teria mais trabalho pra garantir que tudo está corretamente configurado em cada máquinha, mas de qualquer forma é uma possibilidade.